# Lambda returning ConditionalCheckFailedException instead of updating item

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to get my Lambda function to update the results in my DynamoDB table, yet I only want to update my existing entries/items in my table, and not create new items.

I currently have the following:

```
def updateDynamo(asset, averageRating) : 
    updateItem = ChipRatingTable.update_item(
        Key={
            'AssetID': asset
        },
        UpdateExpression="SET AverageRating = :a",
        ConditionExpression='attribute_exists(AssetID)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':a': Decimal(str(averageRating))
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
```

I have tried to do a bit of research and have noted the ConditionExpression as the way of doing it, yet every time I try that I get an error:

> "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ConditionalCheckFailedException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The conditional request failed", "errorType": "ConditionalCheckFailedException"

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is the error I get:

 "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ConditionalCheckFailedException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The conditional request failed",
  "errorType": "ConditionalCheckFailedException",

Comment: Your example code doesn't fit the error message. You probably used ConditionExpression, but it's missing in the example code.

Comment: Yea sorry, made an edit on it, updated it again with what I was actually using!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update '**AssetID**' then try this, it works for me. This code will update only AssestID's **AverageRating** value.

```
   response = table.update_item(
          Key={
                'AssetID': asset
             },
         UpdateExpression='SET AverageRating = :val1',
         ExpressionAttributeValues={
              ':val1': '676767'
         }
    )
```